# Orion CB does not change the value of an attribute (corrected)

Tags: fiware-orion

**UPDATE:** The problem seems now to have been corrected in the "global" Orion instance.

I try to change an attribute of an entity but it does not seem to have the
wanted effect. The same code worked well 2 months ago, as I recall. What to do with it now?

I have the entity `cie_test_1` with the float attribute `test_1` in the "global" Orion Broker `http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026`. I understand that the intention of the broker is to propagate changing values. However, it seems that the value cannot be changed. Details of the transactions are below.

Version information of the broker is

```
{ 
  "orion" : { 
    "version" : "0.19.0", 
    "uptime" : "0 d, 0 h, 2 m, 31 s", 
    "git_hash" : "1ad73b298cd261861203fbffb9c789f6ade2796d", 
    "compile_time" : "Wed Feb 11 13:00:19 CET 2015", 
    "compiled_by" : "fermin", 
    "compiled_in" : "centollo" 
  } 
}
```

## Transmit value request

### Request

```
POST http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/cie_test_1/attributes/test_1
Host: orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,fi;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Auth-Token: <my auth token>
Content-Length: 14
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Payload:

```
{"value":"50"}
```

**NOTE:** Attempted to set `value` = **50**

### Response from the Orion

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Auth-Token, Tenant-ID
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 07:52:29 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Payload:

```
"statusCode" : {
  "code" : "200",
  "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
}
```

Firefox browser didn't like the response:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 14 of the JSON data

Better JSON response might be:

```
{
  "statusCode" : {
    "code" : "200",
    "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
  }
}
```

## Value query from the Orion

### Query

```
GET http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/ngsi10/contextEntities/cie_test_1
Host: orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,fi;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 0
Content-Type: application/json
X-Auth-Token: <my auth token>
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
```

### Response from the Orion

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, X-Auth-Token, Tenant-ID
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 289
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 10:09:27 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

Payload:

```
{
  "Success: {
    "contextElement" : {
      "type" : "",
      "isPattern" : "false",
      "id" : "cie_test_1",
      "attributes" : [
        {
          "name" : "test_1",
          "type" : "float",
          "value" : "10"
        }
      ]
    },
    "statusCode" : {
      "code" : "200",
      "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** `value` is still **10**

Comment: JSON syntax error is a bug in Orion that we have acknowledge and hope to solve in the next version https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/772. Next, I'd have a look to your test in order to understand why the value is not being updated.

Comment: I have done the same tests and it seems to work (you could have a look to my command secuence here: https://gist.github.com/fgalan/b74b057399e6f8e2ed98, note Orion runs in localhost, but it is your same version, i.e. 0.19.0). Note that I'm starting with an empty database, which is not exactly the same setup.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the result of the following shell command `echo 'db.entities.find({"_id.id": "cie_test_1"})' | mongo orion`? It will provide me more insight into your DB content what may be related with the issue

Comment: I have realized that you are using the Orion global instance at orion.lab.fi-ware.org, so you cannot run the above command as you don't direct access to DB. However, I can do it :) and, after that, I have found the problem. I will post an answer in the next days.

Comment: The problem with JSON encoding mentioned in my first comment has been fixed in develop branch( PR https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/776), thus the fix will be included in the next Orion version released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is related with [service path functionality](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Entity_service_paths) and, in particular, with the the following fix introduced in 0.19.0 version:

> Fix: internal substitution of servicePath defaults ("/" for
>   update-like operations, "/#" for query-like operations)

Let's consider the following situation: an entity document exists in the DB but it was generated using an Orion version previous to 0.19.0, thus without servicePath field, i.e:

- id = E1
- type = T1
- servicePath = [null]
- attr.test_1 = 10

Now, Orion 0.19.0 processes an updateContext APPEND on [E1, T1] (note the POST in your question has APPEND semantics). That doesn't result in updating the previous entity document, but in creating a new entity document:

- id = E1
- type = T1
- servicePath = "/"
- attr.test_1 = 50

Thus, now we have 2 documents in entities collection in the DB, almost equal but not exactly equal. In fact, if you use queryContext on [E1, T1] with service path "/" or without servicePath (wich implicitely mean "service path is not relevant for the query") you will get both in the response, one with 10 and other with 50 fo the test_1 attribute.

However, convenience operations based on GET doesn't work the same as queryContext (at least in the current Orion version). Convenience GET assumes that only one document is going to be put into the response and in this ambiguous case it takes the older one (i.e. the one which modification date annotated in the DB is older). In other words, the one with test_1 value to 10.

The solution to this is to fix the database in order to "merge" the 2 entities document into one (with servicePath = "/"). For orion.lab.fi-ware.org (the case in your question), the FIWARE Lab staff will do that in the comming days. For private Orion instances, the merge_default_sp_dups.py script is provided to do it (check [database migration procedure for 0.19.0](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Upgrading_to_0.19.0_and_beyond_from_any_pre-0.19.0_version) for more information).

**UPDATE:** orion.lab.fi-ware.org DB has been fixed. You shouldn't have the updating problem described in your question any longer.

Comment: Seems to work now.

By the way, my reason to use the POST request (instead of the PUT specified for the purpose) to change the value of the attribute is that the "global" Orion instance seems to have the POST in the list of CORS approved operations but no PUT.